# IndentationErrorがreturnの箇所で出る原因が分からない

Tags: python, python3

大学の課題でライフゲームのプログラミングをPythonで行っているのですが、インデントエラーが出る理由が分かりません。
cellの調べたい成分の周囲に１が何個あるかを数えるプログラムで、戻り値は0~8までの整数値が出力されます。

どなたか原因を教えていただく思います。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-984a1d963c13>", line 12
    return int(count)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

**ソースコード:**

```
cell = [[0,0,1],
        [0,1,1],
        [1,1,0]]

def count_neighbor(cell, i, j):

    count = 0

    for x in range(len(cell)):
        for y in range(len(cell[x])):
        
            try:
                if x == y != 1:
                    if cell[i+x-1][j+y-1] == 1:
                        count += 1
            except:
    return int(count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

原因は`try: except:`の`except:`時の処理が記述されていないためです。

目的の機能を完成させるためにはどうだか分かりませんが、エラーを解除するためだけなら、例えばこんな感じに`pass`でも入れてみてください。

```
cell = [[0,0,1],
        [0,1,1],
        [1,1,0]]

def count_neighbor(cell, i, j):
    count = 0
    for x in range(len(cell)):
        for y in range(len(cell[x])):
            try:
                if x == y != 1:
                    if cell[i+x-1][j+y-1] == 1:
                        count += 1
            except:
                pass
    return int(count)
```